# Value is still wrapped up in an Option even after if let statement

Tags: rust

I have a struct with two fields, *state* and *children*. Children is an option that contains a vector of children. I am using if let syntax to deconstruct this option back to the vector.

```
fn main() {
    let mut root = Node::new2d(3);
    loop {
        root.calc_scores(100);
        if let Some(mut children) = root.children {
            let child = children.pop();
            root = Node {
                state: child.0,
                children: None,
            }
        }
        root.make_children();
    }
}
struct Node<T> {
    state: T,
    children: Option<Vec<(T, i32)>>,
}
```

The above code doesn't compile. It complains that child is of type `Option<(Board2d,i32)>`.
Why is child still wrapped up in an option enum? Doesn't `if let Some(mut children) = root.children{}` take the vector out of the Option enum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`pop` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.pop) on a `Vec` returns an `Option`, because the `Vec` can actually be empty and thus return `None`, you should check that too.

That being said, `Option<Vec<_>>` is not something you will often need. It only makes sense if you really want a difference between an empty vector and no vector at all, which doesn't seem to be the case here. so you'd end up with something as follows:

```
fn main() {
    let mut root = Node::new2d(3);
    loop {
        root.calc_scores(100);
        if let Some(child) = root.children.pop() {
            root = Node {
                state: child.0,
                children: vec![],
            }
        }
        root.make_children();
    }
}
struct Node<T> {
    state: T,
    children: Vec<(T, i32)>,
}
```